# ¿Cómo cerrar un proyecto en VSCode?

Tags: vscode

quisiera saber si este ide puede cerrar proyectos ya que me molesta ener tantos abiertos, ni siquiera puede ocultarse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Con la combinación

> CONTROL + K + O

seleccionas un proyecto para abrir

Comment: las 3 teclas al mismo tiempo?,

Comment: No, mantén apretado CTRL.